# Maximum number of variables in method

Tags: c#

I was here idle, so I had this curiosity,
Someone can tell me what's the maximum number of variables per method in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no known limit on *count of variables*, also because any variable can have different size, but there is a *memory limit* on execution  *stack size*.

Quoting Brian:

> The default stack size for a .NET application is 1 MB (default is 256
>   KB for 32-bit ASP.NET apps and 512 KB for 64-bit ASP.NET apps), but
>   you can change that. For the application you can change the default
>   size by modifying the PE header of the executable. For threads you
>   create, you can use the constructor overload that takes a stack size.

[Stack capacity in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823724/stack-capacity-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I tried making a method with more than 65534 local variables (see my answer), and it could not compile. They were of reference type. 65535 references on the stack should not exceed 1 MB (but as I said it failed already at compile-time). This was the Visual C# compiler that comes with VS2012 (that's C# 5).

Answer (score 20):

I just tried to compile a generated program source with 26*26*26*26 local variables, not method parameters, (they were called `@aaaa`, `@aaab`, `@aaac` and so on), and I hit this limitation:

> error CS0204: Only 65534 locals are allowed

Comment: I've had also reached it generating source code.. :D