# Stream to UTF8 String, without the byte[]

Tags: c#, .net, performance, character-encoding, stream

I have a stream whose next *N* bytes are a UTF8 encoded string. I want to create that string with the least overhead.

This works:

```
var bytes = new byte[n];
stream.Read(bytes, 0, n); // my actual code checks return value
var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

In my benchmarking I see considerable time spent collecting garbage in the form of `byte[]` temporaries. If I can get rid of these, I can effectively halve my heap allocations.

The [`UTF8Encoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding(v=vs.110).aspx) class doesn't have methods for working with streams.

I can use unsafe code, if that helps. I cannot reuse a `byte[]` buffer without `ThreadLocal<byte[]>` which seems to introduce more overhead than it alleviates. I do need to support UTF8 (ASCII won't cut it).

Is there an API or technique here that I'm missing?

Comment: Note to self: http://bjoern.hoehrmann.de/utf-8/decoder/dfa/

Comment: You could subclass `Stream` to make a `TruncatedProxyStream` that wraps the original stream and reads at most `n` bytes from the underlying stream.  Then pass that to a `StreamReader`.

Comment: How big are these `byte[]` temporaries?  Is the problem that you are allocating lots of tiny arrays, or a few large arrays that end up on the [large object heap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951836/why-large-object-heap-and-why-do-we-care)?

Comment: @dbc, what would it read them into? Ideally I was an implementation that writes directly into a string's backing data char[].

Comment: @dbc I'm trying to maximise throughput. Many of the strings will be relatively short, though there is no upper bound.

Comment: Both Encoding.UTF8.GetString as a ReadBuffer in StreamReader with an encoding pass through this method [GetChars](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/encoding.cs,1271) which is probably the source of the allocations you see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't avoid allocation of `byte[]` if you use the UTF8 encoding which is variable length. So the length of the resulting string can be determined only after reading all of these bytes.

Let's see the [`UTF8Encoding.GetString`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/cad15a8edd04c4f6.html) method:

```
public override unsafe String GetString(byte[] bytes, int index, int count)
{
    // Avoid problems with empty input buffer
    if (bytes.Length == 0) return String.Empty;

    fixed (byte* pBytes = bytes)
        return String.CreateStringFromEncoding(
            pBytes + index, count, this);
}
```

It calls the [`String.CreateStringFromEncoding`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/0095ab455b1ed8d8.html) method which gets the resulting string length first, then allocates it and fills it with characters without additional allocations. The [`UTF8Encoding.GetChars`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/9024c8d7cd344301.html) allocates nothing too.

```
unsafe static internal String CreateStringFromEncoding(
    byte* bytes, int byteLength, Encoding encoding)
{
    int stringLength = encoding.GetCharCount(bytes, byteLength, null);

    if (stringLength == 0)
        return String.Empty;

    String s = FastAllocateString(stringLength);
    fixed (char* pTempChars = &s.m_firstChar)
    {
        encoding.GetChars(bytes, byteLength, pTempChars, stringLength, null);
    }
}
```

If you will use a fixed length encoding, then you can allocate a string directly and use `Encoding.GetChars` on it. But you will lose performance on calling `Stream.ReadByte` multiple times since there's no `Stream.Read` that accepts `byte*` as an argument.

```
const int bufferSize = 256;

string str = new string('\0', n / bytesPerCharacter);
byte* bytes = stackalloc byte[bufferSize];

fixed (char* pinnedChars = str)
{
    char* chars = pinnedChars;

    for (int i = n; i >= 0; i -= bufferSize)
    {
        int byteCount = Math.Min(bufferSize, i);
        int charCount = byteCount / bytesPerCharacter;

        for (int j = 0; j < byteCount; ++j)
            bytes[j] = (byte)stream.ReadByte();

        encoding.GetChars(bytes, byteCount, chars, charCount);

        chars += charCount;
    }
}
```

So you already use the better way to get strings. The only thing that could be done in this situation is implementing the `ByteArrayCache` class. It should be similar to [`StringBuilderCache`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/a6dbe82674916ac0.html).

```
public static class ByteArrayCache
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static byte[] cachedInstance;

    private const int maxArraySize = 1024;

    public static byte[] Acquire(int size)
    {
        if (size <= maxArraySize)
        {
            byte[] instance = cachedInstance;

            if (cachedInstance != null && cachedInstance.Length >= size)
            {
                cachedInstance = null;
                return instance;
            }
        }

        return new byte[size];
    }

    public static void Release(byte[] array)
    {
        if ((array != null && array.Length <= maxArraySize) &&
            (cachedInstance == null || cachedInstance.Length < array.Length))
        {
            cachedInstance = array;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var bytes = ByteArrayCache.Acquire(n);
stream.Read(bytes, 0, n);

var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
ByteArrayCache.Release(bytes);
```

Comment: Just to close the loop, there's no unsafe `Stream.Read(byte *buffer, int offset, int count)` method on `Stream` that would allow n bytes to be read from the stream into an unsafe array.  If there were, then copying the logic of `CreateStringFromEncoding()` might be performant.

Comment: The other problem with calling `ReadByte` this way is that EOS (-1) is not detected. It seems the limitation here is that there's no way of getting multiple bytes from a stream without using an array. I did try reusing a thread local array but found it hurt performance. Not completely sure why though, so I'll try a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't want to implement their own array re-use logic and don't want to deal with unsafe code either there's the [`ArrayPool<T>` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1?view=net-5.0) available for .NET Core, .NET 5+, .NET Standard 2.1+ and the [`Span<T>` struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=net-5.0).

### Using `ArrayPool<T>`

As the name suggests it allows you to reuse arrays therefore reducing the GC overhead.

Your code would look something like this:

```cs
// rent an existing byte array instead of creating a new one
var bytes = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(n); 

// do your thing ...
stream.Read(bytes, 0, n);
var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

// return the rented array so it can be reused. 
//Optionally you can tell the array pool class to clear it too if you want an empty array in the next reuse-cycle.
ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(buffer);
```

### Using `Span<T>`

If you are certain that your stream length `n` will never get too big you could even use `stackalloc` and `Span<T>` making your code even faster as the GC isn't involved at all (stack memory is cheap).

```cs
// Create your buffer.
Span<byte> bytes = stackalloc byte[n];

// do your thing ...
stream.Read(bytes);
var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

// don't need to free or GC collect anything. Your buffer will just be popped off the stack once the method returns.
```

Again be careful you don't overflow your stack with huge values of `n`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823724/stack-capacity-in-c-sharp) about the Stack capacity in c#.