What is .net 8 x64 process default stack size (for stackalloc)
In my net 8 app I use Span/stackalloc to fast allocate some data structures. I use the following pattern
float[] myDataRent = null;
Span<float> myData = numberToAllocate <= maxStackAllocSize ? stackalloc float[numberToAllocate] : (myDataRentRent = ArrayPool<float>.Shared.Rent(numberToAllocate));
...
if( myDataRent != null )
    ArrayPool<float>.Shared.Return( myDataRent );

My performance measurements show a very high performance gain of stackalloc, so I would prefer  to use stack allocation to as far as possible. Therefore I need to know the maximum safe value for maxStackAllocSize.
So what is the default stack size for 64 bit net core process? According to what I read it should be 4 mb (then I consider 2 mb safe to use for stackalloc), but GetCurrentThreadStackLimits check gives me something close to 1.5 mb and not a very round number. Don't know if I can trust it.

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/823724/5133585

I saw this discussion, but not really. It is about 32 bit processes and very old.

.NET itself imposes various different limits, but much lower: 128b https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/bfea8721763fb3df129e5171e6dc8884446eb5da/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/BinaryWriter.cs#L359 and https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/bfea8721763fb3df129e5171e6dc8884446eb5da/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/BinaryReader.cs#L17 and 256b https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/55e3c59db40a1274aea67cf6a2fc44ee470973d2/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/Common/JsonConstants.cs#L12 ...

... and https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/55e3c59db40a1274aea67cf6a2fc44ee470973d2/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Globalization/CompareInfo.Utf8.cs#L79 and in Unix https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/bfea8721763fb3df129e5171e6dc8884446eb5da/src/libraries/Common/src/Interop/Unix/System.Native/Interop.ReadLink.cs#L33 and 512b https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/55e3c59db40a1274aea67cf6a2fc44ee470973d2/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Globalization/Normalization.Icu.cs#L51 etc

Also note that you can start a thread with a very small stack size if you want https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-threading-thread-ctor(system-threading-threadstart-system-int32) down to 256kb

@Charlieface I don't want to start a thread with a small stack. If it comes to that, I may have started a thread with the bigger one. But for now the question is just: what is the default thread stack size for 64 bit net core app.

I was saying it's not safe to rely on the default stack size because someone might set it lower. So the question is moot. I would have thought anything over 1Mb is not safe, and I've shown you what the .NET coders did in this exact situation.


but GetCurrentThreadStackLimits check gives me something close to 1.5 mb and not a very round number

The value is 0x180000, this number is configured in this file: Microsoft.NETCore.Native.Windows.targets.
But this is not the maximum safe value, it is obvious that there are already many functions on the stack before entering the main method. This limitation can be increased by modifying the SizeOfStackReserve field in the PE header, but it is usually not recommended to allocate more space on the stack than one system page size (Environment.SystemPageSize)

Yes, this looks similar to what GetCurrentThreadStackLimits returns. So, my limits would be closer to 1 mb, definitely not 2. Thanks!

The runtime itself is far more conservative than this as I mentioned above. The stack size can also be manually set when creating a thread.
